# JQuery - ScrollBar

Tags: jquery

Estou desenvolvendo uma barra de rolagem em `JQuery` para um elemento, uma `div`, preciso que a barra fique do tamanho certo pra fazer a rolagem, estou postando o código com o erro para ver se vocês me ajudam:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWKOGO)

Fica a barra de um tamanho não responsivo, tentei usar `$( window ).width()` na medição mas não deu certo.

Comment: Qual é o tamanho certo? É o tamanho da janela? Você não define o tamanho da barra de scroll, você define o tamanho da div onde está a de scroll

Comment: a barra tem q ser proporcional do conteúdo e do tamanho da div, se o conteudo for maior ela é menor e se o conteudo for menor ela é maior...igual a barra padrão do navegador...

Comment: Humm, não percebi bem. Tem algum exemplo que esteja a seguir?

Comment: o que está no codepen

Comment: Cara, você pode explicar melhor a pergunta, o que exatamente é proporcional. E ela não estão proporcional ou não está responsiva??

Comment: se vc habilitar o overflow vai notar q a barra que eu criei está diferente da barra do navegador e teria que ser do mesmo tamanho pois ela tem q funcionar como se fosse a do navegador!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seria isso?
http://codepen.io/goblinbr/pen/dXPLoW

```
function barra() {
    var larguraVisivel = $(".conteudo").width();
    var larguraTotal = $(".conteudo2").width();

    var perc = larguraVisivel / larguraTotal;
    var tamanho = larguraVisivel * perc;

    var left = $(".conteudo").scrollLeft() * perc;
    $(".barra1").css('margin-left', left);
    $( ".barra1" ).width(tamanho);
}
```